# How to restrict buckets to user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Thanks for previous reply.

I am new to amazon s3. Is there way to restrict the buckets to specific user. I have 20 buckets in my amazon s3, while creating the user i want to share only 2 buckets. I wont share remaining buckets to that particular user.How to hide or restrict buckets to particular user. is this possible in amazon s3..??

Answer (score 0):

You speak of a user, is the user someone within your application, or a user in AWS ACL?

If its in the application, you can use a temporary access by generating a presigned URL to serve, code sample in C#:

```
Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest req = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
        req.WithBucketName(Helper.AppConfig.AWS_Bucket)
            .WithKey(key)
            .WithExpires(expiration)
            .WithVerb(Amazon.S3.Model.HttpVerb.GET);

        return S3Helper.S3ClientInstance.GetPreSignedURL(req);
```

If its a user you have added in AWS, you can set the permission for that given user, at the bucket level.

Comment: I have created user from IAM policies, and accessing the buckets through mozilla S3Fox plug in. I gave certain limitation for the user(ie) restrict the user for download and upload the file from unassigned buckets. but i consider that when i hide the buckets from the user, the user can never know what kind buckets are available in my amazon s3. is this possible to restrict the bucket control in IAM policies.

Comment: You can set permissions on the bucket, i.e. - List, Upload/Delete, View Permissions, and Edit Permissions.  None of these refer to hiding the bucket altogether.  It may depend on the discretion of the client app (S3Fox) whether it hides or shows buckets due to the permissions set on that bucket.

Comment: I removed all permissions from bucket properties. There is a possible to restrict the user to access in some other buckets which i never assigned to them. at the same time is there possible to Hide the buckets from the user. `{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1313738761103",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket1"
    }
  ]
}`This is what i given in IAM polices, but whenever i access in S3fox(mozilla firefox plug-in) it displays access denied. when i give name to the specific bucket it displays the object.